# Wait for node to finish writing file from https.get response before continuing?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The while loops creates ethereum wallets, downloads robohash avatars according to the generated addresses and writes them to file. gLoops sets the amount of wallets created. I need the excution to wait for the avatar file to download and be written to file before continuing the while loop. I reckon it should be done with async/await but can't wrap my head around it

```
let gLoops = 0;
while (gLoops < 10) {

pKey = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
wallet = new ethers.Wallet(pKey);
address = wallet.address;

let url = urlBase + address;

https.get(url, (response) => {
    let filePath = `${arg1path}\\avatars\\${address}.jpg`;
    let stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

    response.pipe(stream);
    stream.on("finish", () => {
        stream.close();
        console.log("Download Completed");
    });
});

gLoops++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the async await functionality for your functions?

Comment: There is no async/await for `https.get` in the question or the streams.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your `https.get()` in a promise and use `await` to make the `for`loop pause for it to complete:

```
function processAvatar(pKey, wallet, address, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, (response) => {
            let filePath = `${arg1path}\\avatars\\${address}.jpg`;
            let stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

            response.on("error", reject);

            stream.on("finish", () => {
                stream.close();
                console.log("Download Completed");
                resolve();
            }).on("error", reject);

            response.pipe(stream);

        }).on("error", reject);
    });
}


async function run() {
    for (let gLoops = 0; gLoops < 10; ++gLoops)
        let pKey = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
        let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(pKey);
        let address = wallet.address;
        let url = urlBase + address;
        await processAvatar(pKey, wallet, address, url);
    }    
}

run().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Alternately, you can use one of the http request libraries mentioned [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) that are already promise-aware and use them directly.  My favorite in that list is the `got()` library and it supports streams for the way you are using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is just what I needed. I'll look into Promises. p.s. I reckon C/C++ would be a better choice for sync tasks like this one

Comment: @bitbar - There's no particular reason I know of why C/C++ would be better at this than nodejs.  You just need to learn how promises work in nodejs and use an http library that supports them.  This is required for most programming in nodejs these days so it's just something to learn to use the nodejs programming environment effectively.